# I want to make a spinner in android such that it acts as dropdown instead of poping out

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

[image]

In that image ..the button that shows the settings is like a spinner that dropsdown ...So I want to make such a spinner that dropsdown..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I don't see any spinners in that picture...

Comment: Sorry but on the left side , there is a button of settings, that acts like a spineer and on pressing that the that button shows 2 new buttons of sound and info as shown in figure... I am really sorrie...

Comment: the image link is gone?  Did Lukas edit it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that your example wasn't implemented as a Spinner, since there are only 2 items you don't get much benifit from using a Spinner instead of just making your own "dropdown" layout, and simply making it visible upon the press of the button.

If you have relatively few things that you want in your drop down I would suggest just going that route and staying away from Spinner for this one.

If you have a long list of data that the user will be choosing from though and you are wanting to make it into a dropdown (similar to combo box etc.) you could probably do it by overriding Spinner, to change the way that onDraw() works to display inline with the View in its parent, rather than popping out. Though honestly I think the stock spinner would provide better user experience than this.

Comment: So what should I do to make a drop down list by overriding SPinner onDraw method as I dont know.... Please explain @Tim ...